# cocoa - Shows cover when application is on background mode like itunes

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm developing a application that plays music like itunes and it plays when the application is in background! That has a Audio Session started and it's receiving the remote controls events...

My Question is:

Is it possible to show the Album cover and the music title like itunes when my application is in background?

thanks